# Is there way to make the virtual keyboard appear over any app?

Tags: keyboard

I've noticed that some apps need a keyboard to play and I was wondering if there was any way to make the virtual keyboard appear anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

In many apps I can long-press the Menu button to bring up the keyboard.

Comment: isnt that what opens up google now?

Comment: @user1762507 I have no idea what that is, but probably it depends on your ROM.